# Performance in reading and writing to file in java

Tags: java, file, io

I have a sample code to read and writing to file. when I run this code for 5000 count files its run in 4 min but when number of files increase(example 80000)time is running too high. How to fix this problem?

Here is my code snippet:

```
public class MyExample {
static int count = 0;
static String sessionId = null;
static String date = null;
static List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
static Set<String> sessions = new HashSet<>();
static List<String> sessionList = new ArrayList<>();
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    try {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Path> paths = parse("C://myFolder");
        System.out.println("count is :" + count);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(totalTime);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static List<Path> parse(String folder) throws IOException, SQLException {
    final List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(folder), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                                         BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                    process(file);

            return super.visitFile(file, attrs);
        }
    });

    return paths;
}

private static void process(Path path) throws XPathException, IOException, SQLException {

    sessionId = getSession(path);

    if(sessions.add(sessionId)) {
        sessionList.add(sessionId);
        date = readTimestamp(path);
        Files.walk(Paths.get(path.getParent().toString())).forEach(filePath -> {
            if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
                files.add(filePath.getFileName().toString());
            }
        });
        if (!files.isEmpty()) {
            writeToExcel(new SessionData(sessionList.get(sessionList.size() - 1), files, date));
            files.clear();
        }
    }
    if(sessions.size() > 100){
          sessions.clear();
     }
   } 
  }
```

Comment: which version of Java you are using? If you are using Java 8 you can use **Parallel stream** for efficient reading and writing. Also, would be better if you post some logs indicating the startup and end timings.

Comment: @PraveenKumar  I put more code . please see that. thanks.

Comment: At which point your code is slow? I guess the main processing time is consumed at `writeToExcel(...)`.

Comment: I don't know exactly. it works when number of files is few (5000 files) speed.